# commandnameprefix=always do not resolve clashing definitions of \highlight and \comment, any advice?

Tags: comments

Despite I put \usepackage[commandnameprefix=always]{changes} on the preamble, I still receive error for :

> LaTeX Error: Command \comment already defined.
> LaTeX Error: Command \highlight already defined.

Could you please tell me what is wrong with my preamble below?

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyc,natbib,citestyle=authoryear, style=apa]{biblatex}

\usepackage[commandnameprefix=always]{changes}

\DeclareSortingScheme{nyc}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{\citeorder}
}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage[indent=0cm]{parskip}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=5cm]{geometry}

% Table                                       
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[font=normalsize,labelfont={bf}]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{easyReview}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{authblk}
%\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

Comment: the verbatim package and the easyReview package both define \comment.

Comment: if you move verbatim to the end, there will be no error (and its definition will win).